# How can I express my appreciation for something that I don't enjoy?

Tags: synonyms, appropriate

Films like the Clockwork Orange and Requiem for a Dream make me feel uncomfortable. I find them disturbing and it's not an accurate description to say that I 'enjoy' watching them. However, I do find films like the Clockwork Orange and Requiem for a Dream extremely interesting and powerful. To say that I 'like' or 'enjoy' these films doesn't adequately mirror my feelings.

*Edit:* I'm looking for a word or a phrase to better describe my appreciation?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you hit the nail right on the head when you said "interesting and powerful". Something negative may also be impressive in a grim but respectable way. I tend to describe these feelings as intrigue or respect.

Comment: As a side note, I believe that was the reason Facebook added more specified reactions to posts. It's a bit of a faux-pas to "like" someone's post about their relative or dog dying.

Comment: You can say that the movie was "not bad".

Comment: **Interesting...**

Comment: I think it's fine to say you found a movie powerful, important, extremely well done, etc. In other words, the truth. There are a lot of movies that aren't *enjoyable* for normal people, *A Clockwork Orange* being one of them.

Comment: "I was **riveted** by the movie" and synonyms : fascinated, engrossed, gripped, captivated, enthralled, intrigued, spellbound, rapt, mesmerized, transfixed

Comment: Add **Fargo** to that list and put them in the category of: *"Movies you have to watch... once."*

Comment: @Oldbag I would recommend the TV drama version of Fargo. It is a must watch show. :-)

Comment: Just use the words you'd use for Aunt Edith's mince pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that it was ***"edifying"*** - something that is good for us but not necessarily enjoyable.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/edifying

You could also say that you found it very ***moving***, which again implies that it may not have been enjoyable.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/moving - 2nd defn

Comment: Saying a film is *moving* hits the nail on the head! Saying it is edifying is also an interesting concept. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! Feel free to mark it as correct,  or even just vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say you **appreciate** the movies for the reasons you've just stated, as well as saying you didn't like watching them and they weren't "your cup of tea".

Comment: This is not the feeling I'm trying to convey. Yes, I appreciate them. Saying that they weren't "my cup of tea" is not representative. I appreciate them in the way you appreciate art.